# How to use bitcoin-python

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, python

I'm trying to create a bitcoin address with the [bitcoin-python](https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-python) library.  I tried this code:

```
import bitcoinrpc
bitcoinrpc.connect_to_local().getnewaddress()
```

But I got this error:

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I am running the bitcoind daemon.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?
or can someone direct me to an easier way to learn to develop with bitcoin -

Comment: Check bitcoind's log, which is `debug.log` in its configuration directory.  It should contain some additional information.  I suspect you forgot to set the RPC user name and password in bitcoin-python's configuration to allow it to connect to bitcoind.

Comment: Is bitcoind running? That's the error you would get if bitcoin weren't listening on its port.

Comment: For easier way I am working with this Python project: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets - expect 0.1 release in few days.

Comment: Ok now there is a release http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptoassets.core and tutorial file:///Users/mikko/code/cryptoassets/cryptoassets/docs/build/html/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have not enabled JSON-RPC server in your `bitcoin.conf`.

You need to have:

```
# Enable JSON-RPC
server=1

# Username and password
rpcuser=foo
rpcpassword=bar

# This must be enabled for gettransaction() to work
txindex=1
```

For more information see

http://cryptoassetscore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends.html#module-cryptoassets.core.backend.bitcoind

Answer (score 0):

Richard Kiss has made a nice library for creating/manipulating bitcoin addresses using python here: https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin

That may be easier than getting RPC to work.